# How to use google Application Resource Bundle for internationalize

Tags: html, internationalization, arb

I am developing a web application containing static pages. I want to i18n those static pages.

I would like to use google arb files to achieve this.

I tried example given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181295/i18n-for-static-html-content)

I am getting error saying arb is not defined. Any idea what could be the reason?

-- Raghu

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it started working. Only problem I see is it is still showing red in IntelliJ but working while opening in browser with proper locale