# How to NOT hard code text in Html?

Tags: html, xml, web

I have searched all over internet for what I figure has to be a trivial question.. How on earth do I make a basic web app without hard coding any text to it?!? This seem to be the first lesson to learn but nowhere can I find how to properly do this..

I made a web app some time ago using Google Script, back then I modified the DOM server side before serving it to client - and easily switched all text to placeholders which I could easily lookup in my database and replace with the correct wording and language -

```
<h1>{{myHeader}}</h1>
```

would be served as:

```
<h1>My Header</h1>
```

if English was the desired language.. The database just kept something like

```
{'en': {'myHeader':'My Header', 'myOtherPhrase':'I hate computers sometimes'}, 'sv':{...}}
```

Now I'm trying to advance a bit from Google Script and are writing the same web app again but I can't understand where to start and/or what direction to take?

I want absolutely zero hard coded words / text.. I don't want to do 5 different sites in 5 hard coded language, and I don't want to be the only one who are able to change a misspelled word but I want to create a simple admin tool for other people who know nothing about programming take care of that themselves.

Nowhere can I find a straight answer saying THIS is how you DO it in 2017..

- I looked up XML... that seems very outdated and old-school?
- I checked up node.js and tried to learn.. but didn't. I can't figure out how to do things server side as before.. Besides, it seems as modifying the DOM as a string server side before serving client (templated Html in Google script) is very amateur-ish as it has absolutely zero SEO as far as I'm concerned of SEO.. I can't imagine this is how google would do themselves.
- I saw a few examples where people are putting out tags then looping through the DOM to replace them client side.. Which also seem a really slow and bad idea, where the tags often are visible for a second for the user before changed (not to mention the lacking of SEO again).
- Then I've seen a lot of examples of people hardcoding. I do not want to do that...

There just HAS to be an obvious way. Please world enlighten me...

I'm hosting my app on Firebase... Thanks!

Comment: "as a string server side before serving client (templated Html in Google script) is very amateur-ish" So you don't want to use tags and then replace them via pre-processing? so no server side or client side processing?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. But I usually approach this with simple javascript libraries. i18next or polyglotjs. Both can use json for data storage

Comment: @MJoraid - it just seems to me as server side pre-processing will make SEO terrible.. but I might be wrong.. if I am, I still have to learn how to do it (what to learn to be able to move on)?

Comment: A project I worked on a while ago with a team used constants. There were php files filled with constants and their values only. One file e.g. called en.php and at the first line you would see HOME_PAGE = "Home Page"; and so on so forth for all keywords and paragraphs that appeared on the website. Once we get an order to do a second language, we would send that file to a translator and they will translate the values. The new file will be called e.g. fr.php and we would edit the php code to call fr.php when the user selects so from the website.

Comment: Later on, we developed an admin tool which will fetch the constant php files, display the constants and their values in admin panel to allow modification through a web browser, and then saves the text with the keywords to the database. 
But all this is reinventing the wheel. I suggest you use some sort of CMS framework to manage the website's contents.

Comment: @JapanGuy - I looked up i18next and it seems interesting, although it seems to be more of a translation service at the first glance, correct me if wrong? I'm not used to work with libraries. What I want to accomplish is to have all text on my web app dynamic, with the option of serving multiple languages. I just need a direction on what to learn and I'll go there.. All help appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to mention that we used the constants that we put in en.php within our websites html. E.g. <li class="menu" > HOME_PAGE </li> and it will be handled by php similarly to the way php handle variables. So HTML won't be processed like a string (perhaps?).  And maybe you can use Cache that will store the processed HTML (language ready without constants) and serve them to the clients. By this, you have eliminated the need to pre-process pages every time a client request one. We used an old framework called SMARTY template engine (many moons ago) that helped with cache.

Comment: https://killnoise-84fbb.firebaseapp.com/?lang=sv&country=se is where I'm at right now.. I obviously want to figure out the best way of serving this site in Swedish, and English if I change the querystring to lang=en, and not hard code any text..

Comment: @JohnAlfredsson it can provide automatic translation without translation files. But i ve never used it. For my last project I had to use 4 languages, so I used polyglotjs with 4 language json files. I was looking around just now and saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208485/6468413. I think for starters, this could be helpful for you

Comment: That seems interesting! Will look into! May I ask - Ive seen websites commonly have a lang attribute in the Html tag.. Whats that commonly used for?

Comment: @JohnAlfredsson Joomla! CMS, for example, uses the lang tag when you enabled multilingual website. I think that is to make crawlers know they language of the website so Google indexing will be able to categorize the website's contents.